Index changed from \thepage to \theenumi and alike
This is a sequel of An Index for an Enumerate Document.
I tried to replace \thepage by \theenumi or \theenumii with no success.
Here is a NWE :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%
\makeatletter
\def\makeindex{%
  \newwrite\@indexfile
  \immediate\openout\@indexfile=\jobname.idx
  \def\index{\@bsphack\begingroup
             \@sanitize
             \@wrindex}%
  \def\indexx{\@bsphack\begingroup
             \@sanitize
             \@wrindexx}%
    \typeout
    {Writing index file \jobname.idx}%
  \let\makeindex\@empty
}
\def\@wrindex#1{%
   \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1}{\@currentlabel}}%
 \endgroup
 \@esphack}
\def\@wrindexx#1#2{%
   \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
      % {\string\indexentry{#1}{\@currentlabel}}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1}{#2}}%
 \endgroup
 \@esphack}

\makeatother
%
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Item1}. Item 1.\index{Item1}
    \item \textbf{Item2}. Item 2.\index{Item2}\indexx{Item22}{999}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{Item3}. Item 3.\index{Item3}
        \item \textbf{Item4}. Item 4.\index{Item4}
        \item \textbf{Item5}. Item 5.\index{Item5}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Item6}. Item 6.\index{Item1}
\end{enumerate}
%
\printindex
%
\end{document}

I created \indexx with two arguments to be able to put and try different replacements for \thepage. I tried 999, \thepage, \theenumi, \theenumii. All failed except 999, and I don't understand why. A question of category ? (I am not an expert in TeX)


page numbers need to be held in a non-immediate write until the pagination is done, but enumerate labels you need the opposite, an immediate write while the label is current.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%
\makeatletter
\long\def \protected@immediate@write#1#2#3{%
      \begingroup
       \let\thepage\relax
       #2%
       \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
       \edef\reserved@a{\write#1{#3}}%
       \immediate\reserved@a
      \endgroup
      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}

\def\@wrindex#1{%
   \protected@immediate@write\@indexfile{}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1}{\@currentlabel}}%
 \endgroup
 \@esphack}


\makeatother
%
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Item1}. Item 1.\index{Item1}
    \item \textbf{Item2}. Item 2.\index{Item2}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{Item3}. Item 3.\index{Item3}
        \item \textbf{Item4}. Item 4.\index{Item4}
        \item \textbf{Item5}. Item 5.\index{Item5}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Item6}. Item 6.\index{Item1}
\end{enumerate}
%
\printindex
%
\end{document}


Thanks so much David. With this difference between immediate and not-immediate, I understand now why I could add \theenumi in the text and why it didn't work in the \index.
The mods work in the MWE, but in the real context, the "normal" makeindex works but not the modified version, no index at all being produced. The modified version with the dummy "999" instead of \theenumii works though. Any idea why ? Interaction with other packages ?

@user1771398 perhaps something else is re-defining \@wrindex or you are using a package with a different \index implementation that does not use that internal command. you could ask another question but check what's written to the .idx file  if that is wrong the makeindex program can;t generate an index

The modified version with the dummy "999" instead of \theenumii works so the redefinition of @wrindex works.
